# jqplot replot not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqplot

I am trying to replot my jqplot chart.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var dataseries = [[[10,20]]];

 var plot = $.jqplot('placeholder', dataseries ,
        { title:'<%= @question.text%>',
          axes:{
        yaxis:{min:-100, max:100, tickInterval:10, showTicks:true, label:"<%=@question.ylabel1%>"},
        xaxis:{min:-100, max:100, tickInterval:10, showTicks:true, label: "<%=@question.xlabel1%>"},
        y2axis:{min:-100, max:100, tickInterval:10, showTicks:true, label:"<%=@question.ylabel2%>", show:true},
        x2axis:{min:-100, max:100, tickInterval:10, showTicks:true, label:"<%=@question.xlabel2%>", show:true}},

          seriesDefaults:{showLine:false},
          series:<%=itemNames.html_safe%>,
          highlighter:{
        show:true,
        tooltipContentEditor:tooltipContentEditor}

        });
});

function tooltipContentEditor(str, seriesIndex, pointIndex, plot) {
    return plot.series[seriesIndex]["label"];
}


$("#placeholder").bind("jqplotClick", function(ev, gridpos, datapos, neighbor) {

    var x = Math.round(datapos.xaxis);
        var y = Math.round(datapos.yaxis);
      var item = $('li.item_button_selected').attr('id');
      if (item > 0){
        var requestObj = {
          question_id: "<%=@question.id%>",
          user_id: "1",     
        }
        requestObj["item_id"]=item
        requestObj["x"]=x
        requestObj["y"]=y
            plot.series[0].data = [[50,50]];
            plot.replot();

BLAH BLAH BLAH...
```

<%=itemNames.html_safe%> typically looks like this: [{label:"Winona Ryder"},{label:"Paris Hilton"},{label:"Margaret Thatcher"},{label:"Snooki"},{label:"Natalie Portman"},]

The chart draws fine when the page loads; when I click on the chart, nothing happens.  I know the click is being caught; if I put an alert in there, I see it.  Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, figured it out.  I needed to declare the "plot" variable as a global variable outside of $(document).ready(function()...  Now it's working!

Answer (score 4):

I suggest that you put your event handler in `$(document).ready()` as well -- sort of the corollary to what you posted.

By the main reason I wanted to respond was to note that since we're using jQuery why not "attach" it [more directly](http://www.jqplot.com/deploy/dist/examples/selectorSyntax.html) to the jQuery element.  To do this you would use:

```
$('placeholder').jqplot(data, options);
```

and now the plot becomes:

```
$('placeholder').data('jqplot');
```

so you could replot this example with:

```
$('placeholder').data('jqplot').series[0].data = [[50,50]];    
$('placeholder').data('jqplot').replot();
```